# Field value not printing in custom component

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

For some reason the Field value is not printing into my customComponent const.

```
const CustomComponent = function(field) {
  console.log(field.input.value); //blank, no value
  return (
    <div>
      <input { ...field.input } type={field.type} placeholder={field.placeholder} className={field.className} />
    </div>
  );
}

......

<Field name="test" component={CustomComponent} type="text" placeholder="Test" value="testvalue" />
```

Comment: Can you type in the input and still see nothing but `undefined` printed in the log? Your code looks just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're trying to set the `value` of the `redux-form` `Field` component directly, but the whole idea of `redux-form` is, that you let the library take care of that.

If you want to set the initial value for a redux-form `Field`, use the `initialValues` -prop to do that (see ["Initialize from state"](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/initializeFromState/) example in the docs)

Just stick the redux `connect` -decorator above the `reduxForm` -decorator and you can use redux state to set initial form values

```js
class MyForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        { /* This one will have the static initial value */ }
        <Field
          name="staticValue"
          component={ CustomComponent }
          type="input"
          placeholder="Static Placeholder"
        />
        { /* This one will have the dynamic initial value */ }
        <Field
          name="dynamicValue"
          component={ CustomComponent }
          type="input"
          placeholder="Dynamic Placeholder"
        />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = reducers => {
  return {
    initialValues: {
      staticValue: 'some static default initial value',
      dynamicValue: reducers.dynamicReducer.dynamicValue
    }
  }
}

@connect(mapStateToProps)
@reduxForm({ formName: 'MyForm' })
class MyFormContainer extends Myform {}
```

Hope this helps!